# Where does the subject go when asking a question with ir + a + infinitive?

Tags: futuro

In questions, the subject (if present in the sentence) goes after the noun, such as

> Tú estás aquí.

becoming

> ¿Estás tú aquí?

and

> Stormblessed está comiendo una hamburguesa.

becoming

> ¿Está Stormblessed comiendo una hamburguesa?

If I use the construction of a conjugation of ir + a + infinitive, how does that work? Would it be

> ¿Va Stormblessed a comer una hamburguesa?

or

> ¿Va a Stormblessed comer una hamburguesa?

or something completely different?

Comment: It looks like you didn't realize that you can convert *Tú estás aquí* to a question by just slapping the question marks on and adjusting the intonation.  Well, you can, and it's quite common.  And then you can do the same when you have a more complex verb.  Certainly with a hard to pronounce subject like *Stormblessed* it's even more likely that this will be the approach taken.

Comment: yup, in spanish you only need to add the question marks to make it a question. when you talk you just change the entonation and it will make perfectly sense

Comment: for ir + a verb: It's just like English in terms of the inversion. The subject and auxiliary are inverted, unless you're doing the intonation thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is two questions in one, actually. The first one is, how does one use the *ir a* + infinitive construction, and the second one, which is hidden in there, is what is the preferred word order in Spanish.

*Ir a* + infinitive has two subparts: the verb *ir* (conjugated as needed) and the unit formed by the preposition *a* plus the infinitive of the main verb. **In general** you don't insert anything between *a* and the main verb (see below).

The order tends to stay the same too: wherever you place the subject and possibly other things, *ir* and *a* + infinitive will appear in that order in most cases (again there are exceptions; see below).

It's not strictly true that in questions the normal subject-verb order is inverted as in English. Spanish has a much freer word order than English and the subject might change places depending on a lot of factors, including emphasis, the particular verb in use, and even what sounds better. The inversion rule you have learned is just a good approximation.

In your particular example you would say

> *¿Va Stormblessed a comer una hamburguesa?*

but you could equally say

1. *¿Stormblessed va a comer una hamburguesa?* (no change in order)
2. *¿Va a comer Stormblessed una hamburguesa?* (subject after verb phrase)
3. *¿Va a comer una hamburguesa Stormblessed?* (subject at end)

No. 1 shows you that in Spanish yes-no questions can be asked just by raising the tone at the end, without changing the word order.

No. 2 suggests that *va a comer* is perceived as an inseparable phrase (so there's a inversion: SVO becomes VSO, but V is not the verb *va* but the whole phrase *va a comer*).

No. 3 shows you how the subject can even be moved to the end; to me this sounds as if the subject were not so important, being already more or less established in the conversation, while the object (*una hamburguesa*) is the thing I'm interested in, so it appears before.

Don't let this all discourage you; some of these things are very subtle and you'll learn them, if it comes to that, after exposure to actual native speakers.

Remember "see below"? Well, you actually **can** insert something between *a* and the infinitive. Mostly adverbs: *Va a **rápidamente** comer una hamburguesa.* Or even adverbial phrases: *Va a **de una vez por todas** comer una hamburguesa.* But it tends to sound odd and clumsy, so you generally don't do that.

Also, you can invert the order and say, for example, *A comer una hamburguesa va.* It's rather unusual, though. It can be done for metrical effect in poetry, or for contrast: *A comer una hamburguesa va, pero a comerla con lechuga jamás.* Which more or less means: "Eating a hamburguer, that he will, but eating it with lettuce, (he) never (will)."